# JButton only show up on mouseover

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jbutton

I'm working on a "Tron" game, and for my menu I used a paint method to paint a background to the menu. Everything is good except that the 3 JButtons are "hiding" behind the background until I put my mouse over it then it appears. If there is a way to keep the buttons visible, I would appreciate it!

My code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Menu extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String name;
    Image bk;
    public Menu() {
        super("TRON");
        // Set the size of window
        setSize(800, 800);
        // Set the default operation for the window
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set a background
        ImageIcon ibk = new ImageIcon("background.jpg");
        bk = ibk.getImage();
        // Set a new panel
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        // Make buttons!
        JButton b = new JButton("Play!");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("High Scores");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Exit");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new GameFrame();
            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new hsview();
            }
        });
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        // Set the GridBagConstraints to organize the layout
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets (15, 15, 15, 15);
        // Use gbc to space out each button
        gbc.gridx = (0);
        gbc.gridy = (0);
        // Add them to the panel then to JFrame
        p.add(b, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = (0);
        gbc.gridy = (1);
        p.add(b2, gbc);
        gbc.gridx = (0);
        gbc.gridy = (2);
        p.add(b3, gbc);
        // Add to the frame at the bottom
        add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    // Background stuff
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(bk, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: Change:

    `g.drawImage(bk, 0, 0, null);`

To:

    `g.drawImage(bk, 0, 0, this);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing uses a "layering" concept for it's painting...

`paint` calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  By overriding `paint` and failing to call `super.paint`, you've prevented the component from painting it's various layers.

In Swing, it is preferred to use `paintComponent` to provide custom painting, which allows you to paint underneath any other components that might be added to the component.

[image]

```
public class TestPaint01 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestPaint01();
  }

  public TestPaint01() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    public TestPane() {
      try {
        BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image.jpg"));
        //backgroundImage = background.getScaledInstance(-1, background.getHeight() / 4, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        backgroundImage = background;
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(new JButton("Hello"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return backgroundImage == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(this), backgroundImage.getHeight(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth(this)) / 2;
      int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight(this)) / 2;
      g.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
    }

  }

}
```

You might find [A Closer look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) informative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call the pack() method and this display for your frame. I think the pack() method sets your components up to display.

Here are the steps listed for the JFrame tutorial.

[How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I think the OP needs to stop using `paint`.  `pack` is used by the `JFrame` to determine the preferred size of the child components, so you don't need to call `setSize` *"Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents"*