# What is wrong with my Swing application?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

**EDITED 2/2/2013**

With the help of some of your answers and a simple Swing application guide I found, I was able to make a little bit of progress and I put it all in one class for now. However, I still can't get it to close and I had to make a button to do it because it was getting really annoying having to pull up task manager. The tooltips aren't working either. I don't know if it matters, but I'm doing it in Eclipse.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Thing extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Thing()
    {
        setTitle("Thing");
        setSize(1024, 768);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setToolTipText("A panel container");

        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        quit.setBounds(50, 60, 80, 30);
        quit.setToolTipText("A button component");
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(quit);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Thing thing = new Thing();
                thing.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error it gives when I try to close it with the X. (The closing works fine with the button)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/awt/TimedWindowEvent
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Just a note: You should load the image in the constructor, and then store a referance to the image, instead of loading the image each time you want to draw it.

Comment: `g.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.jpg"), 0, 0, null);`  Do not try to load the image in a paint method!  Read it when constructed (or better, define a constructor that accepts an `Image`). And simply paint it in paint.  So presuming it is a class attribute named `image` that might become.. `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`

Comment: 1) `Title` should return a preferred size of (presumably) 1200x1200. 2) Once you've done that, `pack()` the frame and `setLocationByPlatform(true)` 3) Unless this image is intended to be a BG for other components, consider displaying it in a label. 4) Forgot to highlight the reference to `this` in the final code snippet.  A `JPanel` implements `ImageObserver`, so use the object itself for the image load notification.  A repaint will be triggered as more of the image becomes available.

Answer (score 2):

> For some reason, I can't close it and have to use task manager.

Use `SwingUtilies.invokeLater()` to create GUI.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to change anything. I copied the code on the website and pasted it into the main() method and then cut and paste all of my code where it says createAndShowGUI(); Is that all I need to do or did I misunderstand? It still gives the same error and I'll put that into the original post now.

Answer (score 1):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image.jpg")` is likely using a background loader to load the image off the main paint thread (or Event Dispatching Thread, AKA EDT).

This basically means, the method will return immeditly, but the image won't actually have loaded.

This was done (way back in the olden days) for low capacity bandwidth systems, to prevent the systems from stalling while images where downloaded and loaded into memory.  Now days, this is much less of a concern.

Instead, in the constructor of `Title` you should pre-load the image...

```
private BufferedImage background;
public Title() throws IOException {        
    background = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
}
```

And in your `paintComponent` method...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (background != null) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

The other problems with you current approach to loading the images deals with how it handle errors.  Your current method will tend to silently consume the errors and it's difficult to determine what's actually gone wrong.

You could take a look at [JButton only show up on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431251/jbutton-only-show-up-on-mouseover/14431376#14431376) for more of a complete example

Comment: Thank you, the image works fine now but the window still won't close without task manager. I'll read the link you gave when I get a chance.

Comment: It sounds like you have something else (like a loop or blocking action &/or Thread.sleep or Object#wait) within the EDT, which will stop the EDT from responding to the close event

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you fixed your problem, but I had a similar problem: For my application I extended JFrame, but was not able to close or hide it with any setDefaultCloseOperation(...). I got the same error you showed above when minimizing, restoring or maximizing the frame.
**I fixed it** updating both jdk and jre to **latest Java 1.7** and using it. In eclipse, go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` and select your latest Java **if working on 64 bit System, best use also 64 bit Java**. In the submenu `> Execution Environment` select your Java 1.7 on the left hand and compatible Java 1.7 64 bit JRE on the right hand.
I'm not sure what exactly was the problem, but possibly some incompatibility between Java 64 bit Application and 32 bit runtime environment I guess.

Comment: This was just something I was doing for fun so I haven't gotten back to this yet. I'll get to it soon; that sounds like it would probably work though.